# Can't get data from Firebase Database to show in dropdown - Angular

Tags: angular, database, typescript, firebase, select

I've been scouring the internet, watched every video on YouTube and have even taken two courses on Udemy and can't seem to find this answer. I'm simply trying to take an observable pulled from firebase and put it into a dropdown.

I am getting the data from Firebase as I can display it on the page using list. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Here is my code:

**.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-three',
  templateUrl: './home-three.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-three.component.scss']
})

export class HomeThreeComponent  {
  jobCategory$;
  
  
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
   
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.jobCategory$ = this.db.list('/jobCategory').valueChanges();
      }
  
  }
```

**my .html**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
             <select>                 
                                        
                                               
               <option>All Categories</option>
               <option *ngFor="let jobCategories of jobCategory$" [ngValue]="jobCategories"> 
                                            {{ jobCategories }}  
                                       
                                    </select>
                                        <!--This needs to pull categories from database -->
                                        
                                                    
                                    </div>
```

I've tried converting it to an array using

```
//this.jobCategory = Array.of(this.jobCategory$)
```

When I did this and changed up the .html I was able to get [object Object] to show in the dropdown, but that's as close as I've gotten.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t valueChanges an observable? Try *ngFor="let jobCategories of jobCategory$ | async"

Comment: I did try that as well and just did again to make sure I didn't miss something. When I used this, nothing shows up in my dropdown except for the manually input "All Categories"                                                                                                                                                     <option>All Categories</option>
                                              <option *ngFor="let jobCategories of jobCategory$ | async"> 
                                                {{ jobCategories }}  
                                             </option>

Comment: Try to subscribe to fetch the data, as suggested in one of your answers. Then, as it sounds like you are receiving Objects, not strings, use the JSON pipe on the interpolated observable inside your option (after changing the ngFor to loop the data received in the subscribe):
{{ jobCategories | json }}

Answer (score 1):

I would first be semantic, in essence:

```
// see how jobCategory is the singular and jobCategories$ is the plural
// keep the async pipe for subscription
ngOnInit(){
      this.jobCategories$ = this.db.list('/jobCategory').valueChanges();
      // make sure you see categories here
      this.jobCategories$.subscribe(categories => console.log(categories));
}
...
<option *ngFor="let jobCategory of jobCategories$ | async" [ngValue]="jobCategory"> 
                                            {{ jobCategory }}  
                                       
                                    </select>
```

Also, check out the `subcribe`. Make sure that `console.log` outputs the categories and not an empty array. I suspect this query gives you an empty array and therefore you don't see any `option` tags.

Comment: I made all of these changes. I'm getting an Array of the 5 items I've implemented into the database in the console [0 "Category1" 1 "Category2", etc], but nothing in the dropdown itself. I feel like this got me closer. Thank you.

Comment: @AngularNewbie copy that output into a code block and paste it here

Comment: [Log] Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode. (vendor.js, line 35302)
[Info] [WDS] Live Reloading enabled. (vendor.js, line 89704)
[Log] Array (5) (vendor.js, line 78570)
0 "Force Protection"
1 "Security"
2 "Unmanned Aviation"
3 "Manned Aviation"
4 "Intelligence "

Comment: Array Prototype

concat(value, ...)

constructor: function()

copyWithin(targetIndex, startIndex, [endIndex=length])

entries()

every(callback, [thisArg])

fill(value, [startIndex=0], [endIndex=length])

filter(callback, [thisArg])

find(callback, [thisArg])

findIndex(callback, [thisArg])

flat()

flatMap()

forEach(callback, [thisArg])

includes(searchValue, [startIndex=0])

indexOf(searchValue, [startIndex=0])

Comment: join([separator=","])

keys()

lastIndexOf(searchValue, [startIndex=length])

length: 0

map(callback, [thisArg])

pop()

push(value, ...)

reduce(callback, [initialValue])

reduceRight(callback, [initialValue])

reverse()

shift()

slice([startIndex=0], [endIndex=length])

some(callback, [thisArg])

sort([compareFunction])

splice(startIndex, [deleteCount=0], ...itemsToAdd)

toLocaleString()

toString()

unshift()

values()

Symbol(Symbol.iterator)()

Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true,

Comment: findIndex: true, …}

Object Prototype

Comment: Sorry I had to do it in several comments. I dropped down the Array Prototype to give you as much data as I could in case you needed it. Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: @AliF50 - forgot to tag you.

Comment: Could it be that there is a *ngIf preventing it from being painted?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try taking out the function call from valueChanges().

*You also need the async suggestion made above.

So this line

```js
this.jobCategory$ = this.db.list('/jobCategory').valueChanges();
```

should look like this

```js
this.jobCategory$ = this.db.list('/jobCategory').valueChanges;
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but it didn't change anything. I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Prefer objects over list. It will help you to access values as well as keys.
For me this worked.

```
db.object('/jobCategory')
  .valueChanges()
  .subscribe((inp) => {
    this.jobCategories = inp;
    console.log(this.jobCategories);
  });
```

Output will be in key-value format.

```
{1:"jobcategory1",2:"jobcategory2"...}
```